# How can i get the absolute path in a FreeBSD syscall openat?

Tags: c, kernel, freebsd

I'm writing a simple programe to hook freebsd syscall.
 Like this

```
static int
openat_hook(struct thread *td, register struct openat_args *uap)
{
  uprintf("  SYS_openat: \"%s\", flags: %d, mode: %X\n", uap->path, uap->flags, uap->mode);
  return sys_openat(td, uap);
}
```

This do not print a absolute path.

When I'm in user space, I can get the absolute path by realpath.
But, I don't know how to get a absolute path in kernel.

Comment: So how does `realpath` do it?

Comment: @AndrewHenle   In kdump, this funtion called __getcwd, i found it in syscall table, but i can't find the implementation of this function,

Answer (score 1):

You can't (reliably) get the path. openat() opens a relative filename relative to the given file descriptor of a directory. So you would have to first find out the absolute path of an open file descriptor. The directory for the descriptor might not exist anymore, might be outside the programs filesystem namespace (chroot, pivot_root, switch_root, containers,... cause that) or something might be mounted over it.

Under Linux /proc/self/fd/ is a symlink showing the absolute path of the FD. So the kernel sort of knows the absolute path for an FD. BSD might have a similar thing for you to use to get the path of an FD. But even then the path might not be valid because of the reasons given above.

Comment: Most likely, `open( ... )` is implemented as `openat( AT_FDCWD, ... )`, so most calls to `sys_openat()` are likely to actually be simple `open()` calls.  And if you can't reliably get the path of the file referred to by the file descriptor, the `openat()` call itself becomes unreliable.

Comment: @AndrewHenle The kernel has a handle for the open file descriptor going back to the underlying filesystem. The handle is reliable but might not have a valid path. For example `int fd=opendir("/tmp")`. Then mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /tmp. What would be the path for fd? "/tmp" now points to a different filesystem but openat(fd, "foo") will open a file on the old one. -- True about open() using openat(AT_FDCWD, ...). You can catch those cases. You simply can't make it reliable as there are cases that have no valid path.